# How to update JavaScript after executing a function?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Good day to all, I'm new to js, so I would like to ask you, after executing the function, I add a response with content via innerHTML, but this content should also work with javascript, but it works, so I have to restart the page, how to do it right so that my functions work with the added answer?

Need to run this code

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-comment-like, .btn-comment-dislike').forEach((e) =>
e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const commentRatingButtons = this;
    const commentRatingId = commentRatingButtons.getAttribute('data-id');
    const commentRatingAction = commentRatingButtons.getAttribute('data-action');
    const commentTotalRating = document.querySelector(`button[data-comment-rating='${commentRatingId}']`);
    const commentMessageRating = document.querySelector(`div[data-comment-message='${commentRatingId}']`);
    fetch(`/api/comments/${commentRatingId}/${commentRatingAction}/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        },
    }).then((response) => response.json()).then((result) => {
        if (result['error']) {
            commentMessageRating.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="alert alert-danger rounded-0 shadow-sm me-2 align-self-start mb-2" role="alert" style="padding:2px;">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-hexagon-exclamation"></i> ${result['error']}!
                    </div>`
        } else {
            if (commentRatingAction === 'like') {
                commentMessageRating.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="alert alert-success rounded-0 shadow-sm me-2 align-self-start mb-2" role="alert" style="padding:2px;">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-face-smile"></i> Спасибо за оценку, ${result['author']}!
                     </div>`
            } else {
                commentMessageRating.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="alert alert-danger rounded-0 shadow-sm me-2 align-self-start mb-2" role="alert" style="padding:2px;">
                       <i class="fa-solid fa-face-frown"></i> Спасибо за критику, ${result['author']}!
                     </div>`
            }
            commentTotalRating.innerHTML = `${result['comment_total_rating']} <i class="fa-solid fa-hand-holding-heart"></i>`
        }
    })
})
)
```

after doing this

```
commentForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
const commentForm = this;
const commentFormSubmit = commentForm.querySelector('#commentSubmit');
const commentArticleId = commentForm.getAttribute('data-article-id');
const commentEmpty = document.querySelector('#emptyComments');
const commentNestedList = document.querySelector('.nested-comments');
 commentFormSubmit.innerText = "Ожидаем добавления...";
 commentFormSubmit.disabled = true;
fetch(`/api/articles/${commentArticleId}/comments/create/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        },
        body: new FormData(commentForm),
    }).then((response => response.json()))
    .then((result) => {
        if (result['comment_is_child']) {
            const commentParentThread = document.querySelector(`#comment-thread-${result['comment_parent_id']}`);
            commentParentThread.innerHTML += `
            <ul id="comment-thread-${result['comment_id']}">
                <li>
                <div class="card mb-3 nth-shadow border-0 rounded-1">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-2 d-none d-sm-inline pe-0">
                          <img src="${result['comment_avatar']}" class="img-fluid rounded-1 nth-img-comment nth-shadow" alt="{{ node.author.username }}">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                         <div class="d-flex flex-row gap-2">
                            <div class="card-title">
                               <h6 class="nth-card-user-username mb-0"><a href="#">${result['comment_author']}</a></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nth-card-title-username">
                                ${result['comment_created_at']}
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="card-text mb-2">
                            ${result['comment_content']}
                         </div>
                          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary nth-btn-sm btn-like shadow-none" data-id="${result['comment_id']}" data-action="like" type="button">+1 <i class="fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary nth-btn-sm btn-dislike shadow-none" data-id="${result['comment_id']}" data-action="dislike" type="button">-1 <i class="fa-solid fa-heart-circle-minus"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary nth-btn-sm shadow-none" type="button" data-comment-rating="${result['comment_id']}">${result['comment_total_rating']} <i class="fa-solid fa-hand-holding-heart"></i></button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            `
        } else {
            if (commentEmpty) {
                commentEmpty.remove();
            }
            commentNestedList.innerHTML += `
            <ul id="comment-thread-${result['comment_id']}">
                <li>
                <div class="card mb-3 nth-shadow border-0 rounded-1">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-2 d-none d-sm-inline pe-0">
                          <img src="${result['comment_avatar']}" class="img-fluid rounded-1 nth-img-comment nth-shadow" alt="{{ node.author.username }}">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                         <div class="d-flex flex-row gap-2">
                            <div class="card-title">
                               <h6 class="nth-card-user-username mb-0"><a href="#">${result['comment_author']}</a></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nth-card-title-username">
                                ${result['comment_created_at']}
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="card-text mb-2">
                            ${result['comment_content']}
                         </div>
                          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary nth-btn-sm btn-comment-like shadow-none" data-id="${result['comment_id']}" data-action="like" type="button">+1 <i class="fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary nth-btn-sm btn-comment-dislike shadow-none" data-id="${result['comment_id']}" data-action="dislike" type="button">-1 <i class="fa-solid fa-heart-circle-minus"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary nth-btn-sm shadow-none" type="button" data-comment-rating="${result['comment_id']}">${result['comment_total_rating']} <i class="fa-solid fa-hand-holding-heart"></i></button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            `
        }
        commentForm.reset();
        commentFormSubmit.innerText = "Добавить комментарий";
        commentFormSubmit.disabled = false;
        commentFormParentField.value = null;
    })
})
```

I would be very grateful if you direct me to the correctness of creating such methods.

Comment: Use a framework?

Comment: maybe use async....await for the fetch calls?

Comment: no, I don't use js frameworks. It's all rendered on the Django side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are feeling lazy to add it to the function then do something like:

```
let href = "http://"; //the location of your own html file you are working on.
//This will open your file on a new tab
window.open(href, "_blank");
//This will close your own tab.
window.close();
```

In this way you can close and open the tab again if it does'nt work with: "window.location.reload".

Comment: Oh sorry, i did'nt see your comment. I was writing my answer

Answer (score 1):

Put all your js code that you want to reload in a function and simply call it again when you want to. You can also use: window.location.reload();

Comment: i.e. you mean, I need to wrap the code in a function, and after successful rendering, call it again in the js code so that it picks up a new element?

Comment: Yeah! You can add at the starting of the function the method to remove the element first if it exists. OR, you may use window.location.reload to reload the page